# why does the equivalent condition necessary?

Tags: c++, strict-weak-ordering

I have a question on the code piece from [C++ standard library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000K1YANC). My question is that `!(p2.lastname() < p1.lastname())` seems not to be necessary because I think the condition represents the last names are in p1 and p2 equivalent. If I removed the condition, the code seems to work properly. I saw this *strict weak ordering*. I read the relevant article but I did not fully understand the concept. Would you please explain why the condition is required?

```cpp
class Person {
public:
  string firstname() const;
  string lastname() const;
};

class PersonSortCriterion {
public:
  bool operator() (const Person& p1, const Person& p2) const {
    // 1) Compare the lastnames.
    // 2) If the lastnames are equivalent, compare the firstnames.
    return p1.lastname() < p2.lastname() ||
       (!(p2.lastname() < p1.lastname()) &&
          p1.firstname() < p2.firstname());
  }
};
```

Comment: What does `equivalent` mean here?

Comment: `return std::tuple{lhs.lastname, lhs.firstname()} < std::tuple{rhs.lastname, rhs.firstname()};` is easier to understand IMO (Possibly with a `as_tuple` method to factorize), and avoids to break strict weak ordering.

Comment: @Jinchul The second half of your `||` is wrong. You need to use `==` instead of `!<`, which is the same as `>=`, which is not what you want in this situation. `return (p1.lastname() < p2.lastname()) || ((p1.lastname() == p2.lastname()) && (p1.firstname() < p2.firstname()));` Or, use a tuple, like Jarod showed, since it already implements `<` for you.

Answer (score 3):

So I think you are saying that the following is OK

```
return p1.lastname() < p2.lastname() ||
      p1.firstname() < p2.firstname());
```

but that is incorrect. Consider two people "Andy Zerkis" and "Zebedee Archer". Using the code above both AZ < ZA and ZA < AZ. So both names are less than the other one. Not surprisingly this will confuse sorting algorithms. Another way of saying this is that the code above does not impose a strict weak ordering. In particular it breaks the rule that it cannot be that case that both x < y and y < x are true.

Strict weak ordering seems confusing if you aren't familiar with it, but really it just says the obvious things you would expect from any sorting criterion.